# MySQL "table ... is full", roughly 1000 records

Tags: mysql

I have a small MySQL database stored on an Amazon EC2 server (running Windows Server 2008). It's used in a small .Net application (1 user).

I did the most basic installation possible. Didn't edit any configuration file.

Inserting on a table, it says "table is full".
Until yesterday, the EC2 machine had it disk full, so I understand. After cleaning up some space (around 10Mb), the error persists.

The table has 1021 rows, the key is an int(06), auto-increment. All other tables are working just fine. The table in question has like 6 columns (just to store dates and currency exchange rates), and the others (working fine) have like 30 columns.

I have no idea what to do now.

Has the MySQL blocked the table for not recognizing that 10Mb of free space?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at mysqls "repair table" feature and restart the mysql server porcess.

Comment: It recognizes the space, but most probably the table structure on disk is damaged, use sql command `REPAIR TABLE table_name`. Is it MyISAM or InnodDB table?

Comment: if you ran out of disk, then probably the db file is corrupted when it failed to write new records (no space available)...

Comment: Tried the rapair table. Just to found out it's InnodDB, and it doesn't accept rapair table.

Any ideas now?